# Mapping values in nested object in myBatis?

Tags: sql, spring, mybatis

I want to map a nested object with one select query.

For example:

```java
// parent class
public class Parent {
    private String name;
    private Child child;
}
    
// child class
public class Child {
    private name;
}
```

And I want to get whole parent class with one select query.

For example:

```sql
SELECT P.NAME, C.NAME from PARENT P, CHILD C
```

This is just example, please ignore specific grammar.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you have to assign different column alias for `C.NAME` e.g. `SELECT P.NAME, C.NAME C_NAME from ...`. For mapping, see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#association). It's explained as "nested results".

Answer (score 1):

In your Main

```
@MappedTypes(Parent.class)
@MapperScan("com.foo.mybatis.batis.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatisApplication {...}
```

@MapperScan value should locate to your mapper package.

Use this in your interface. @Mapper @Select

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface ParentMapper {

    @Select("select * from parents")
    List<Parent> findAll();
}
```

You can add your custom query in @Select("SELECT P.NAME, C.NAME from PARENT P, CHILD C")

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. But this is what i wanted. What i want is, single query for data, split and save them other objects. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Checkout [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-return-multiple-entities) @sb0321